# How to numerically solve the eigenvalues of a partial differential operator？

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, numerical-calculus

I have a partial differential operator of the following form:
$$L_X=A(X) \frac{\partial}{\partial X} + \frac{1}{2}D(X)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial X^2}$$
where A and B allow to be nonlinear.For example:
$$A(X)=\begin{pmatrix}
   ax+by+x^2+y^2  \\
   cx+dy+x^2+y^2 
\end{pmatrix}$$
Is there any way to numerically calculate the eigenvalues of this operator $\lambda$：
$$L_Xu(X)=\lambda u(X)$$
I've seen many questions with partial differential operators, but they are generally linear, and I don't know how such an equation should be done.

Comment: The equation is linear as a map in the space of solutions u.